# AWX Ansible - Can't access repository Git and Bitbucket

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket, ansible-awx

I have configured and successfully used until some days ago a project in AWX, synchronizing it with a Bitbukcet repository.
Now, when I am trying to sync the Project with the repository, I get this error:

```
TASK [update project using git] ************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin"], "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/user/reponame.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org\n"}
```

I also tried creating a new repository on Github, but during the sync process I get this error:

```
TASK [update project using git] ************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote https://github.com/ansible/ansible-tower-samples -h refs/heads/HEAD", "msg": "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ansible/ansible-tower-samples/': Could not resolve host: github.com", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ansible/ansible-tower-samples/': Could not resolve host: github.com\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ansible/ansible-tower-samples/': Could not resolve host: github.com"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The machine where AWX is installed is able to perform a ping to those hostname and to perform a git clone.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use change https method to ssh method? Setup your keys with github and try using ssh.

Comment: According the type of error message `Could not resolve host: example.com`, it looks like a missing network connection and no DNS available for the software Ansible AWX. Since no information is given how and where the software is installed and configured, more debugging details are necessary. Since it also seems not be a programming problem you should ask this question on an other Stackexchange site.

Comment: @U880D nothing changed after the first configuration of the repository, it suddenly stopped working yesterday.

Comment: @ikora same result; before 2 days ago everything was working perfectly